# How to read muliple values from a config file using config parser

Tags: python

I have made a Config file and have multiple values for a keyword as:

[section]

database: mysql , sqlite

and i want to access the values separately..How to go about it??

Comment: If people have given acceptable answers, you should *accept* their answers. Otherwise, you may find that you get fewer responses to your future questions.

Answer (score 8):

How about using standard [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) and not using comma?

```
[section]

database: mysql sqlite
```

When you get the variable, just split it:

```
databases = configparser.get('database').split()
```

Comment: @rushi: Great! Don't be afraid to accept answers also on your previous questions.

Answer (score 2):

Using space for separating options has the disadvantage that if space is already present in the options, as in the case of file names, it wont work. So better to use comma and split using `.split(',')` and remove leading/trailing whitespaces.